# process multiple entries with conditional imports in webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, html-webpack-plugin

Ok here is the issue:

a.js:

```
export function blah() {}
```

b.js:

```
export function blah() {}
```

Notice that a and b export the same functions, in OOP, basically there is a base class whereby a and b inherit the functions.

c.js:

```
import blah from either "./a.js" or "./b.js";
```

In webpack,
I need to generate two entries, one with c.js importing a.js, while the other with c.js importing b.js, what is the most elegant way to define the configuration in webpack?
I took a look at DefinePlugin, ProvidePlugin, ImportLoader, but still no luck.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I am solving it now using multiple output entries, but I am wondering if there are better answers:

```
var config = [
{
  entry: {
    capp1: './c.js',
  },  
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      renderSrc$: path.resolve(__dirname, './a.js')
    }
  },  
  plugins: [             
   ],  
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
},
{
  entry: {
    capp1: './c.js',
  },  
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      renderSrc$: path.resolve(__dirname, './b.js')
    }
  },  
  plugins: [             
   ],  
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
}];
```

in c.js

```
import blah from "renderSrc";
```